# TLE error when swapping nodes in linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to "Swap Nodes in Pairs" on leetcode (https://leetcode.com/problems/swap-nodes-in-pairs/).

My code is below. It produces TLE error for just 1 test case. I am really not sure it is stucked in infinite loop. Appreciate any help.

```
def swapPairs(self, head):
    """
    :type head: ListNode
    :rtype: ListNode
    """
    ans=h=ListNode(0)
    while head and head.next:
        h.next=head.next
        h.next.next=head
        h=h.next.next
        head=head.next.next
    h.next=head
    return ans.next
```

Comment: Hi @Tommy. Do see my solution and let me know if it helps and if you have any questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I see with your code is this line here `h.next.next=head`. What I am assuming is you are trying to set the adjacent node but what this in fact does is actually set the whole list to `h.next.next` on the first running. This, in turn, is set again here `head=head.next.next` which then simply causes an infinite recursion as you suspected.

Now that you got the key point, I hope you can correct your mistake and implement your solution.

I have re-implemented your solution to the following.

```
class Solution:
    def swapPairs(self, head):
        """
        :type head: ListNode
        :rtype: ListNode
        """
        if not head or head.next == None:
            return head
        first = cur = ListNode(0) #initialize a node object with 0 value
        cur.next = head #get accesss to the first node

        while (cur.next and cur.next.next):
            a = cur.next
            b = cur.next.next
            c = cur.next.next.next

            #swap the nodes here
            cur.next = b
            cur.next.next = a
            cur.next.next.next = c
            cur = cur.next.next # sets it to one before the next node

        return first.next
```